# Приложение для терминала

Tags: платежные-терминалы

Предстоит попробовать написать приложение для терминала (как терминал оплаты мобильного телефона, только на предприятии, для учета посещения работы сотрудниками, например).

Я так понимаю, что пишется обычное веб-приложение, разворачивается а весь экран (F11) и дело с концами? Буду рад любой информации, потому что впервые столкнулся с подобной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть как веб приложение, так и приложения для Windows/Linux. 
Но просто работает в полноэкранном режиме. Ну ещё заблокированы некоторые фичи - переключение задач, панель задач и тому подобное.

Comment: Первая же мысль - отключить возможность выделения элементов на странице, "перетаскивания" картинок... Вешать на все элементы "onMouseMove='return !1;'", например. Приложение для терминалов "Киви" вроде как крутится просто в IE?